# generar archivo csv con php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema al generar un archivo csv y al abrirlo con excel, 
este se abre mostrando todos los datos pero no los separa por columna solo coloca en la columna A aca les comparto el codigo

```
public function generar_excel(){
    $condiciones = $_SESSION['condiciones']['condiciones'];   
    $data_excel = $this->modelo_base_m->seguimiento_excel($condiciones); 
    //prp($data_excel,1);

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"Seguimientos_Menores_5\""); 

    $outputBuffer = fopen("php://output", 'w');


    foreach ($data_excel as $i => $valor) {
        fputcsv($outputBuffer, $valor,';');
    }

    fclose($outputBuffer);
    exit;
    $this->index();
}
```

en la linea del fputcsv le coloco el tercer parametro de punto y coma para que los separe pero de igual forma los coloca en una celda.

Comment: En el bucle `foreach ($data_excel ...`, la variable `$valor` ¿es un array?

Comment: si es un array.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que `$valor` es un array, te sugiero probar estas opciones:

- Cambia el `Content-Type` a `text/csv`.
- Quita la línea `Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary` pues los CSV son archivos de texto (no binarios).

Si lo anterior no funciona, podrías probar indicandole explícitamente al CSV qué separador estás usando. Para esto debes agregar al inicio del archivo CSV una línea que contenga solamente este texto:

```
sep=;
```

Puedes probar abriendo el archivo CSV con Notepad++ y agregando esta línea al inicio, y luego abres con Excel a ver si funciona. Si es así, debes agregar esa línea a tu script php, por ejemplo:

```
$outputBuffer = fopen("php://output", 'w');
fwrite($outputBuffer, 'sep=;' . "\r\n"; // <-- agregar esta línea
foreach ($data_excel as $i => $valor) { // ...
```

Fuentes:

- [Documento RFC sobre el mimetype `text/csv`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)
- [Hilo en superuser.com sobre el uso de `sep=;` en un CSV](https://superuser.com/a/420025)

Comment: Buenos dias, probé todas las opciones que me  comento y nada sigue sin separarlos, los que me parece extraño es que al abrirlo los datos están separados por ";" pero no los toma, tengo otro reporte que esta hecho con los mismos códigos y ese si lo abre separados